How to return values from GridView into Checkbox & GridBox in Windows Form C#
How to retrieve values from GridView in Win.Form C#, for RadioBox and CheckBox. The problem is when I click on a row of user in GridView I get the entered value (textBox) values But, the RadioBox & CheckBox are not (it get conflict) especially when I try to navigate from one row to another row in GridView.
I am trying to enter some values in TextBox , select values from CheckBox,RadioBox and push it to GridView , then retreive it once I click of row of user in GridView to be able to update it without using Database.


A GridView ist not a DataGrid is not a DataGridView and a DataBox doesn't even exist... Always call things by their right name. And never show code as an image!! And take care to use parenthesis correctly, when casting:  ..=(string)(dgv.....Value)

OK thank you for your comment, kindly could you tell how to solve the problem ?

Well, step one is to add the missing paranthesis. As it stands you are not casting the cell values but the DGV as a whole..
